# PyQt4 QtGui.QIcon() not displaying (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, pyqt4, ubuntu-16.04

I am attempting to learn how to use the PyQt4 package for Python. The following code executes as expected on a Windows box but on my Linux box the icon is not displaying:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__() #returns parent object (q main window object)
    self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)
    self.setWindowTitle("PyQt4 Window")

    self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Logo.jpg'))
    self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Anyone have an idea what I need to do to get the image to display on a linux box?

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 and python 3.5.

Comment: The image is on the side of the .py?

Comment: in ubuntu the icon will be displayed in the top bar of your screen.

Comment: Wait, what the hell. It doesn't display the image on the actual popup?? How did I not notice that the icon was displaying the image! I'm not even drunk or anything!

Comment: That method puts the icon to the window, but ubuntu places the icons on the top, it is a very typical error that is why it is indicated. ;)

Comment: So there is no way to get it to display on the actual GUI? Kinda wish when a topic is marked as a duplicate the person marking it would be required to link to the original post he's considering this post a duplicate of. Otherwise, pretty much completely useless to mark a topic as a duplicate.

Comment: That is handled by the OS, it is not handled by the GUI, you could try to eliminate the topbar and create your own topbar, that has been asked many times and answered in SO. On the other hand the link of the duplicate is in the upper part below the title of your question.

Comment: Oh great! Thank you!